# return@methodName - Meaning of that syntax?

Tags: android, kotlin

This code is from an Udemy-course I'm currently doing:

```
if (noteTitle.isNullOrEmpty()) {
    title_et.error = "Title required"
    return@setOnClickListener
}
```

What it is basically doing is clear to me. But what's that 'return@setOnClickListener' statement?

**What's the meaning of these @method-name syntax? What means the @-character here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its [qualified returns](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels).

Consider the following code:

```kotlin
fun foo(strings: List<String?>) {
    strings.forEach {
        if (it.isEmptyOrNull()) return
        println(it)
    }
}
```

Since [`forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) is an inline function, return statement will return from the parent function `foo` instead.

To simply return from one iteration of forEach you qualify to return only on a particular scope:

```kotlin
strings.forEach {
    if (it.isEmptyOrNull()) return@forEach
    // ...
}
```

You can customize it with other name if they are ambiguous:

```kotlin
strings.forEach outer@ { a ->
    list2.forEach inner@ { b ->
        if (a.isEmptyOrNull()) return@outer
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is useful mostly in inline and cross-inline situations, but sometimes you also want to explicitly qualify in non-inline lambdas (just to be more precise) as in the example you mentioned.